# Common Job Titles

Tags: resume, title, recruiting

I work for a very large multinational manufactuting  company in a commercial role.  My employer uses non-standard job titles for my role and I'm wondering if using the "industry standard" title instead of the company assigned title on resume is acceptable.

If, for example, a supply chain professional is assigned a "sourcing manager" title but elects to use "commodity manager" (or vice versa) on a resume to conform to a potential employer's title convention, is this a red flag to HR?  The job descriptions are interchangable for all practical purposes and the typical job duties are identical.  There are many other examples I could use from other professional verticals but I think this conveys my point.

Comment: Fast food workers are titled "associates" so they don't get overtime pay. Some titles have legal consequences.

Comment: Positions in question are lower six figure salaried roles.  Can't imagine what kind of legal ramifications titles would have on these roles...but interesting point.

Comment: The technical side seems to have a more standardized naming convention.  The commercial side seems to be "squishy."  Maybe it's just my perception of the tech vs commercial cultures.

Comment: I remember my first job, the CEO gave us the job titles of "Interaction Engineer".  When you went to say, "look the industry average for a developer is 50% more than we make" he'd say "but you're not a developer , you're an Interaction Engineer, so you can't compare"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your resume, put the title you were given at the company so that the HR drones won't pitch a fit when confirming your employment history.  Use the appropriate space to describe exactly what your responsibilities where.

Titles outside of the "C" ones are pretty much glossed over when a resume is being reviewed.  The relevant information is the job you were performing - which is what the hiring managers actually care about.